# DirectX 11 Shader Reflection: Need help setting Constant Buffers variables by name

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, hlsl, direct3d

I'm creating a system that allows the manipulation of constant buffer variables by name using their byte offsets and byte sizes via Shader Reflection. I can bind the buffers to the Device Context just fine, but none of the cubes in my 3D scene are showing up. I believe this is because something is wrong with how I'm mapping data to the Constant Buffers. I cast the struct, be it a float4 or a matrix to a void pointer, and then copy that void pointer data to a another structure that has the variable's name. Once the shader needs to have its buffers updated before a draw call, I map the data of every structure in the list during the Map/Unmap call with a pointer iterator. Also, there seems to be a crash whenever the program calls the destructor on one of the shader constant structures. Below is the code i've written so far:

I'm mapping the buffer data through this algorithm here:

```
void DynamicConstantBuffer::UpdateChanges(ID3D11DeviceContext* pDeviceContext) 
{
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
HRESULT hr = pDeviceContext->Map(m_Buffer.Get(), 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mappedResource);
if (FAILED(hr)) return;

// Set mapped data
for (const auto& constant : m_BufferConstants)
{
    char* startPosition = static_cast<char*>(mappedResource.pData) + constant.desc.StartOffset;
    memcpy(startPosition, constant.pData, sizeof(constant.pData));
}

// Copy memory and unmap
pDeviceContext->Unmap(m_Buffer.Get(), 0);
}
```

I'm initializing the Constant Buffer here:

```
BOOL DynamicConstantBuffer::Initialize(UINT nBufferSlot, ID3D11Device* pDevice, ID3D11ShaderReflection* pShaderReflection)
{
    ID3D11ShaderReflectionConstantBuffer* pReflectionBuffer = NULL;
    D3D11_SHADER_BUFFER_DESC cbShaderDesc = {};

    // Fetch constant buffer description
    if (!(pReflectionBuffer = pShaderReflection->GetConstantBufferByIndex(nBufferSlot)))
        return FALSE;

    // Get description
    pReflectionBuffer->GetDesc(&cbShaderDesc);
    m_BufferSize = cbShaderDesc.Size;

    // Create constant buffer on gpu end
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC cbDescription = {};
    cbDescription.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    cbDescription.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
    cbDescription.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    cbDescription.ByteWidth = cbShaderDesc.Size;
    if (FAILED(pDevice->CreateBuffer(&cbDescription, NULL, m_Buffer.GetAddressOf())))
        return FALSE;

    // Poll shader variables
    for (UINT i = 0; i < cbShaderDesc.Variables; i++)
    {
        ID3D11ShaderReflectionVariable* pVariable = NULL;
        pVariable = pReflectionBuffer->GetVariableByIndex(i);

        // Get variable description
        D3D11_SHADER_VARIABLE_DESC variableDesc = {};
        pVariable->GetDesc(&variableDesc);

        // Push variable back into list of variables
        m_BufferConstants.push_back(ShaderConstant(variableDesc));
    }

    return TRUE;}
```

Here's the method that sets a variable within the constant buffer:

```
BOOL DynamicConstantBuffer::SetConstantVariable(const std::string& varName, const void* varData) 
{
for (auto& v : m_BufferConstants)
{
    if (v.desc.Name == varName)
    {
        memcpy(v.pData, varData, sizeof(varData));
        bBufferDirty = TRUE;
        return TRUE;
    }
}

// No variable to assign :(
return FALSE;
}
```

Here's the class layout for ShaderConstant:

```
class ShaderConstant
{
public:
    ShaderConstant(D3D11_SHADER_VARIABLE_DESC& desc)
    {
        this->desc = desc;
        pData = new char[desc.Size];
        _size = desc.Size;
    };

    ~ShaderConstant()
    {
        if (!pData)
            return;
        delete[] pData;
        pData = NULL;
    }

    D3D11_SHADER_VARIABLE_DESC desc;
    void* pData;
    size_t _size;
};
```

Any help at all would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: First make sure you are checking the results of all functions that return ``HRESULT`` with the ``SUCEEDED`` or ``FAILED`` macros. I see a number of points that could be failing that you are not checking for success.

Comment: You should post your solution as an "Answer"...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! No answers in the question, please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer. Add the answer in the answer section only.